# Problem with REST ASSURED status code in post

Tags: rest-assured

The whole previous code works.
but when i got to post it doesnt want to check the status code. it gives it like an error. and on the get it doesnt show an error. the message that i get is :

```
java: method statusCode in interface io.restassured.response.ResponseOptions<T> cannot be applied to given types;
  required: no arguments
  found: int
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
statusCode()' in 'io.restassured.response.ResponseOptions' cannot be applied to '(int)'
```

the code is:

```
package RestAssured;

import static io.restassured.RestAssured.*;
import io.restassured.response.Response;
import netscape.javascript.JSObject;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.equalTo;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.*;

public class MoiPrimeri {

    @Test
    public void testGet1(){
    baseURI = "https://petstore.swagger.io";
    given().get("/v2/pet/findByStatus?status=available").then().
            statusCode(200);
    }

    @Test
    public void testGet2(){
        baseURI = "https://petstore.swagger.io";
        given().get("/v2/store/order/3").then().statusCode(200).body("petId", equalTo(2));
    }

    @Test
    public void testPost1() {
        Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        map.put("code", 0);
        map.put("type", "IT");
        map.put("message", "Ivan");
        System.out.println(map);
        JSONObject request = new JSONObject(map);
        System.out.println(request.toJSONString());

        baseURI = "https://petstore.swagger.io";
        given().body(request.toJSONString()).when().post("/v2/pet/2/uploadImage").statusCode(200);

    }}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you miss the `then()` method in Post API.

- Without `then()`, `statusCode()` is getting status code from response, then it return `int`.
- With `then()` - the method chain, it changes the object, `statusCode(200)` means comparing status code.

```
given().body(request.toJSONString()).when().post("/v2/pet/2/uploadImage").then().statusCode(200);
```